# Swift: Hide Scrollview header

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I would like to hide the header of my scrollview.

I have a scrollview

```
//Contains everything inside the view
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
```

which spans across the whole width and height of my view. When scrolling down, a weird header appears and blocks a bit of the scroll view content. I would like to hide that overlay. The worst thing is, that in bright mode, the overlay is white. That clashes with my colors. How do I go about removing it?

[image: Header]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overlay is the navigation bar - it appears as soon as you scroll. To hide it completely, you can set [`navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621885-setnavigationbarhidden). Or, you can pass in a [transparent appearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar#3878455) for [`navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/3198028-standardappearance).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Does what you said it would.